# Oracle EM 11g - query to find out CPU utilization

Tags: oracle

in OEM 11g, if you see performance, there are graph about cpu utilization, memory utilization, and disk I/O utilization.

my question is:

what is the script to see CPU-Utilization history ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This query runs on 11.1.0.7 Enterprise and provides similar results to the the OEM Grid performance page. Both require the diagnostics package.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SAMPLE_TIME, 'HH24:MI ') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
       ROUND(OTHER / 60, 3) AS OTHER,
       ROUND(CLUST / 60, 3) AS CLUST,
       ROUND(QUEUEING / 60, 3) AS QUEUEING,
       ROUND(NETWORK / 60, 3) AS NETWORK,
       ROUND(ADMINISTRATIVE / 60, 3) AS ADMINISTRATIVE,
       ROUND(CONFIGURATION / 60, 3) AS CONFIGURATION,
       ROUND(COMMIT / 60, 3) AS COMMIT,
       ROUND(APPLICATION / 60, 3) AS APPLICATION,
       ROUND(CONCURRENCY / 60, 3) AS CONCURRENCY,
       ROUND(SIO / 60, 3) AS SYSTEM_IO,
       ROUND(UIO / 60, 3) AS USER_IO,
       ROUND(SCHEDULER / 60, 3) AS SCHEDULER,
       ROUND(CPU / 60, 3) AS CPU,
       ROUND(BCPU / 60, 3) AS BACKGROUND_CPU
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SAMPLE_TIME, 'MI') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
               DECODE(SESSION_STATE,
                      'ON CPU',
                      DECODE(SESSION_TYPE, 'BACKGROUND', 'BCPU', 'ON CPU'),
                      WAIT_CLASS) AS WAIT_CLASS
          FROM V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY
         WHERE SAMPLE_TIME > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1'
         HOUR
           AND SAMPLE_TIME <= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MI')) ASH PIVOT(COUNT(*) 
  FOR WAIT_CLASS IN('ON CPU' AS CPU,'BCPU' AS BCPU,
'Scheduler' AS SCHEDULER,
'User I/O' AS UIO,
'System I/O' AS SIO, 
'Concurrency' AS CONCURRENCY,                                                                               
'Application' AS  APPLICATION,                                                                                  
'Commit' AS  COMMIT,                                                                             
'Configuration' AS CONFIGURATION,                     
'Administrative' AS   ADMINISTRATIVE,                                                                                 
'Network' AS  NETWORK,                                                                                 
'Queueing' AS   QUEUEING,                                                                                  
'Cluster' AS   CLUST,                                                                                      
'Other' AS  OTHER))
ORDER BY 1
```

This query is not as good as what Grid displays but it's close.

Comment: am i allowed to set retention of this database which it used for stored performance? if there's no retention, i assume that this database would take a big size of storage just for stored the information of performance. how if i want to select from 1 week ago? and show timestamp per hour?

Comment: @Yoga this is a real time quote.   If you want to use this you need the stats package licence and if you want to see what was happening a week ago you might as well install 11g Grid on a separate server.

Comment: @Yoga Refer to [this page](https://github.com/khailey/ashmasters) for lot more useful scripts.

Comment: @kevinsky i have install 11g Grid, and i can see the graph about performance, but i want the 'number' not just chart.

Comment: @Raj i have still not find the query that i means, but thank you raj

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query the OEM Repository, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT  TARGET_NAME,
        TARGET_TYPE,
        TARGET_GUID,
        METRIC_GUID,
        METRIC_LABEL AS METRIC_GROUP,
        COLUMN_LABEL AS METRIC_NAME,
        TO_CHAR(ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP,
        AVERAGE,
        MINIMUM,
        MAXIMUM
FROM    SYSMAN.MGMT$METRIC_DAILY
WHERE   TARGET_TYPE = 'host'
AND     METRIC_LABEL = 'Load'
AND     COLUMN_LABEL = 'CPU Utilization (%)'
AND     TARGET_NAME = '<hostname>'
AND     ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP >= TO_DATE('05/31/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')
AND     ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP < SYSDATE
ORDER BY    ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP
```

There are several "metric" views. I am utilizing the METRIC_DAILY view. There is also a METRIC_HOURLY, METRIC_CURRENT. Just find which one is right for you.

Comment: i have try this query, but the result is no row. are there something wrong?

Comment: It returns results for me. I am running 12.1.0.3 but since it runs I doubt there are any real differences in the view. Did you update the where clause appropriately?

Comment: i just changed the <hostname> to be my hostname. and nothing changed again after that. but seems no works with me? :(